# Duplicate handling strategy error with gradle while using protobuf for java

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am using the below configuration `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.17"
    id "java"
}

group "de.prerna.aws.tests"
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
  
    protobufVersion = "3.18.1"
}


dependencies {

    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:$protobufVersion"


sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
            srcDir 'src/main/proto'
        }
        java {
            // include self written and generated code
            srcDirs 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {

        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:4.0.0-rc-2'
    }

    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.39.0"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks.generatedFilesBaseDir = 'generated-sources'

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins { grpc{} }
        }
        ofSourceSet('main')

    }
}
```

Error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processResources'.
> Entry Person.proto is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variant of [BParolini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69795588/17865734) for `build.gradle` (Groovy DSL)

```
tasks.withType(Copy) {
    filesMatching("**/*.proto") {
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I could fix this problem by adding the following code to my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks {
    withType<Copy> {
        filesMatching("**/*.proto") {
            duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
        }
    }
}
```

Extra info: I'm using Gradle 7.3-rc-3 and Java 17.

Comment: where exactly do we  need to  use  this method in build.gradle file ?

Comment: It can be placed anywhere in the build script

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately nobody explains reasons for this problem, so here is some of my explorations and guesses. Please correct me if you know more.

If found that following build script code causes this error:

```
proto { srcDir 'src/main/proto' }
```

If look inside "build/extracted-include-protos" directory, there are original .proto files copied into "build/extracted-include-protos/test" (but not into main).

My guess is that those auto-copied .proto files are originally uses as the only sources, but when adding "src/main/proto" source set we give some compiler tool second set of same files.

Removing this srcDir is not a good idea, because it required for IDEA to correctly open included .proto on Ctrl+click (otherwise it is opened extracted copies which is useless).